# How to overlay div on canvas without creating more space

Tags: css, html, canvas

I'm trying to overlay this card that says "A, Snare" with a 30% top and 30% left over the canvas but get this trailing white space to the right of the canvas.  I've attached a picture with the "div.content" highlighted to show you what I mean.  How can I get this card to float above the canvas without any resulting whitespace?

[Trailing white space.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RdSE.png)

```css
#canvas{
  background:black;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

body, html{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}



.content{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  left: 30%;
  top:30%;
  right:-30%;
  position:relative;
}

.card{
  background-color:green;
  width:3%;
  height 100%;
  border: white solid 2px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" resize hidpi=off></canvas>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="card">
          <h1 class="card__title">A</h1>
          <p class="card__description">
            Snare
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Bad idea to base canvas on percent. You do know that percent is based on the parent, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have the width of the `content` set to `100%`. This means that this div has a width of 100% of the screen.
Your `margin-left` is 30%, making the total width 130%. Make your `content`a width of 70% and the problem is solved, as that totals to 100%.

Edit: I made the `card` wider to show the text, just so you know.

```css
#canvas{
  background:black;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body, html{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}



.content{
  display:inline-block;
  left: 30%;
  top:30%;
  width: 70%;
  position:relative;
}

.card{
  background-color:green;
  width:10%;
  height 100%;
  border: white solid 2px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" resize hidpi=off></canvas>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="card">
          <h1 class="card__title">A</h1>
          <p class="card__description">
            Snare
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Remember to select the checkmark next to the answer, as it shows the question as answered to future readers (and reward some reputation to the answerer).